# Integral equality in a matrix setting

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations

While reading a proof I stumbled over the following equation:

\begin{align}
\int_{B_1} \langle A,D\psi(x)\rangle dx=0 \quad \forall \psi\in W^{1,\infty}_0(B_1,\mathbb{R}^2)\forall A\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}
\end{align}
I denote by $\langle\ \ ,\ \ \rangle$ the Frobenius inner product. This looks like something derived by partial integration, which I have never seen in that Frobenius setting. Also in the proof it is implied that
$\int_{B_1} \langle D\psi(x),D\psi(x)\rangle dx=0$ does not hold. I would appreciate any hint why the equation holds and if one can adapt partial integration in that setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can literally just write out the inner product and use the well-know integration by parts formula:
$$
\langle A, D\phi \rangle=A_{11}\partial_1\phi_1+A_{12}\partial_1\phi_2+A_{21}\partial_2\phi_1+A_{22}\partial_2\phi_2
$$
Since your matrix is constant you can just swap the derivates using integration by parts; ill do it for 1 term as an example
$$
\int_{B_1} A_{11}\partial_1\phi_1 dx=-\int_{B_1} \phi_1\partial_1 A_{11}=0
$$
Summing over 4 zero terms is still zero. Boundary terms are getting dropped since your function vanishes on the boundary by assumption.
The second eqzuality only holds when $D\phi=0$ by properties of the scalar product.